# How to prevent browser from displaying recent searches?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, search, browser

I am developing a website with Django and I have a search box where you can search the website and as you type in words, I use ajax to show search results. The problem is, I used the search a few times and now when I type in words in the search box, it displays my recent searches on top of where I want to show the search results.

Here is an example of what I mean: 
say I have previously searched the words 'this' that' then' and 'thus' in my websites search box. Now, when I go to the search box and type in 't', it displays all posts on my website which start with 't' using ajax but on top of that, the browser also displays the recent searches. (this, that, then and thus).

It displays it like how, if you go to facebook or gmail and type in the first few letters of your email then it displays saved email accounts.

How do I disable this feature when using the search box on my website?

Note: I made JavaScript a tag because I'm guessing this is done with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable auto-complete:

```
<form autocomplete="off" ...>
```

Caveat: Some browsers ignore this, some have user options to ignore it, and there are browser extensions that disable it.

Comment: hm thanks, i'm guessing Chromium is one of the browsers which ignore this since it didn't work for me -.-

Comment: Chrome has an option to ignore it, but it's not exposed in the normal Settings page, you have to use `chrome://flags` to find it.

Comment: Banking web sites usually disable autofill of username and password. Is that being ignored when you go to your bank?

Comment: ah wait, when I put "autocomplete='off'" in FORM rather than INPUT, it worked! I'm guessing some browsers check for "autocomplete='off'" in INPUT and some check it in FORM.. I left it in both to be safe.

Comment: That's right, I think it's usually put in the `<form>`, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You would turn off `autocomplete` like this.

```
<input type="text" name="stackoverflow" autocomplete="off">
```